# Node.js module export

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, export

How can I export these variables so I can later use them on different js files?

The following example works well with just 1 variable

```
var app = module.exports = express();
```

But I want to pass more variables so I did this

```
var app = express();

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    password : ''
});

module.exports.app = app;
module.exports.connection = connection;
```

with no success

Comment: The export is required somewhere else, read the manual and you should be able to figure this out, you can export and require just about anything.

Comment: What do you mean, “with no success”? What happened? How are you importing them?

Comment: I get errors on console saying that app has no method get, so its not exported?, the export is inside app.js using just for example module.exports = app; works fine but if I try to also export connection variable it wotn work

Comment: How are you importing them?

Comment: app = require('../app'); and then something like app.get('/index', ...)

Comment: Yes, well, `app` is now `require('../app').app`. If you want to keep that the same, you can set `module.exports = app; app.connection = connection;`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because on the first, your module is the app. I mean that if you have B like that in the first case:

```
app = require('A') // = express()
```

whereas on the second time it is :

```
app = require('A') // = {app: express(), connection: connection}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the Node.js [Modules documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html):

You either assign the value that you want to export to the *module.exports* property, or you assign an object to it.

**mymodule.js:**

```
var app = module.exports = express();
```

*Or:*

```
var app = express();
module.exports = {
    "app": app,
    "otherproperties": "you want to export"
}
```

To require a module that you made yourself and didn't place *node_modules* directory, you can either supply an absolute path or a relative path.

**Calling module:**

```
var app = require("/home/user/myapp/mymodule.js"); // absolute path
app; // access returned value of express() function, created in *mymodule.js*
```

*Or:*

```
var app = require("./mymodule.js"); // path relative to the calling module
// In this case the calling module is in the same directory as *mymodule.js*
app.app; // access returned value of express() function, created in *mymodule.js*
```

**Addendum**: Even though the *modules* library/module has been locked, I really recommend reading the documentation. It's very much possible to read the entire documentation in two evenings while looking up network terminology that you're not familiar with. It'll save you a lot of time in the short term!

Comment: Why isn't this answer accepted? This close the deal.